# Do we get separate control to keyboard and mouse with Windows Virtual Desktop?

Tags: automation, windows-10, windows-virtual-pc

I want to create an automation that used keyboard shortcuts and mouse clicks on the screen to complete the process. I want the automation to run in the background on my laptop. Can this be achieved using the Windows Virtual Desktop on Windows 10?

Can I create a new desktop and let the automation run on that and continue a different on my current desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Virtual Machine to get a virtual desktop, but to get virtual mouse and keyboard you have to use softwares like MouseMux (in beta version).

You will have to attach a separate mouse and keyboard to be used in virtual machine as virtual mouse and keyboard. They will perform mouse clicks and keyboard shortcuts.